# Not able to get element by xpath index (selenium)

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to get a element in a list by specifying index

For example I have this xpath:

```
"//p-dropdown[@formcontrolname='PrimaryRoleId']//ul[contains(@class, 'ui-dropdown-items')]//li[contains(@class, 'ui-dropdown-item')]" and it gives me this:
```

[image]

But when I add [1] at the end of xpath I still get the same thing? How can I get the first (or specific matching element by index)?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to enclose it with parenthesis "**()**"

```
(//p-dropdown[@formcontrolname='PrimaryRoleId']//ul[contains(@class, 'ui-dropdown-items')]//li[contains(@class, 'ui-dropdown-item')])[0]
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks!